# AfterSave on PFUser checking if on creation or update

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am having difficulty in distinguishing between if a PFUser is being updated or if it is being saved for the first time. I implemented the solution found on parse.com [here](https://parse.com/questions/run-cloud-code-aftersave-only-on-create-but-not-for-update). However, it is not working as explained in the answer found at the link. I always get a false regardless of if it is on the creation or an update. Here is the code that I have implemented.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
     Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
     //this error log prints false regardless of if the user is signing up.
     // or having a key updated.
     console.error(request.object.existed());
     if (!request.object.existed()) {
         //This is on sign up, the user has not existed prior. 
         //This doesn't work. This block of code is always run.
     }
     else {
         //This is supposedly when the user is having a key updated.
         //Unfortunately, this code is never run regardless.
     }
 )}
```

This code does not behave as I expect it to because the `request.object.existed()` always returns false. I think this may have to do that this is saving a `PFUser` and not some generic `PFObject`.  Is there something I am missing using `request.object.existed()` on a PFUser afterSave? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an unresolved Parse cloud [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1675561372679121/)

Possible workaround is to check the difference between create and update times to see if your object is being updated or is being created.